# Javafx progress not updating fast enough

Tags: java, javafx

I am parsing large files, line by line, where the file size could go from a few 1000's to millions of lines. When the files are small (e.g., few 10,000s lines), all the components (those indicated by red arrows in the image below) update promptly, line by line thereby giving a true indication of where the process is. When the files are large, there is huge delay in the update, it could take up to 30 seconds before the indicators reflect the progress! I could resize it manually to refresh the display.

[image]

The method that gets called upon streaming though the file line by line is `updateProgress()`. In there, `progressPrevVal` goes from 0 to 1 (each increment being `1.0 / 2,675,150`), and `lineNum` goes from 1 to 2,675,150 if we use the example in the image.

Here is the entire code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class DxProgressIndicator extends Application {

private static ProgressBar pb;
private static ProgressIndicator pi;
private static TextField tfNumbers;
private static Label lblLineNumVal;
private static Label lblAllLines;
private static double progressIncrement;
private static double progressPrevVal;
private static int lineNum;
private static Label lblFile;

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Dexter Parser");

    lblFile = new Label();
    final HBox hbFile = new HBox();
    hbFile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    Label lblCurrentFile = new Label("Current file: ");
    lblCurrentFile.setMinWidth(90);
    lblCurrentFile.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 13));
    hbFile.getChildren().addAll(lblCurrentFile, lblFile);

    pb = new ProgressBar(0);
    pb.setMinWidth(450);
    pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);

    final HBox hbPis = new HBox(10);
    hbPis.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    hbPis.getChildren().addAll(pb, pi);

    lblLineNumVal = new Label();
    lblLineNumVal.setMaxWidth(200);

    Label slash = new Label("  /  ");

    lblAllLines = new Label();

    final HBox hbLines = new HBox();
    hbLines.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    Label lblLineNum = new Label("    Currently parsing Line # :   ");
    lblLineNum.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
    hbLines.getChildren().addAll(lblLineNum, lblLineNumVal, slash, lblAllLines);

    tfNumbers = new TextField();
    tfNumbers.setEditable(false);
    tfNumbers.setMaxWidth(100);

    final HBox hbTrxValues = new HBox();
    hbTrxValues.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    Label lblNumbers = new Label("(transaction, step, record) = ");
    lblNumbers.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
    hbTrxValues.getChildren().addAll(lblNumbers, tfNumbers);

    final VBox vb = new VBox(10);
    vb.getChildren().addAll(hbFile, hbPis, hbLines, hbTrxValues);
    vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    scene.setRoot(vb);
    stage.show();
}

public static void updateProgress() {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        progressPrevVal += progressIncrement;
        pb.setProgress(progressPrevVal);
        pi.setProgress(progressPrevVal);
        lblLineNumVal.setText(Integer.toString(lineNum++));
    });
}

public static void setFileMetadata(String str) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        lblAllLines.setText(str);
        progressIncrement = 1 / Double.valueOf(str);
        progressPrevVal = 0d;
        lineNum = 1;
    });     
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

From the client's main method, once I start the GUI in its own thread like this:

```
    Runnable task = () -> {
        DxProgressIndicator.main(null);
    };
    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    thread.start();
```

I can then go through the file, streaming through it line by line like this:

```
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file)) {
        stream.forEach(line -> {
            DxProgressIndicator.updateProgress();
            // a bunch of stuff to do with the line
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

So, what am I missing? How can I force a refresh so that the components update smoothly at every iteration instead of every almost one minute when processing awfully large files?

Thank you.

Comment: You are probably flooding the FX Application Thread with so many updates that it can't keep up. Use a JavaFX [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), bind the progress properties of your indicators to the task's progress property, and call `updateProgress()`, which will throttle the number of updates. As an aside (and why I can't untangle your code to provide an actual answer): it's not clear why you are driving this from outside the UI class: normally you would launch the loading task in a thread from inside the `start()` method.

Comment: To your second point, I have to build many projects that will go through files line by line but end up doing different things of course. This way, I can use the same application here (namely, the same `updateProgress()` method) to work with any project that streams through files.

Comment: But there are clearly better ways to reuse the same UI structure, that don't involve artificially making everything static. This approach, for example, completely prevents you from being able to open two of these at once, which I would imagine could easily become something of a problem later.

Comment: To your first point, absolutely right - I am apparently flooding the FX thread. I will look into this approach and see if I could code it. Any code-samples is appreciated though :-)

Comment: I see what you mean by updating from within the `start` method. But, in my logic, those `static` properties or methods can be turned into instance ones easily if the need arises, so they are not what decides whether this is a good reusable design or not IMO.

Comment: I guess my point is that if you wanted two instances of the view open at the same time your structure would prevent it. (You wouldn't be able to make the fields static, because you need two of them, and since there's no way to get the instance of the `Application` subclass created by calling `launch()`, there's no way for you to access instance methods of the class either.) Anyway, see answer, in which I reverted to the standard lifecycle instead of this one (because, well, I'm not going to propagate designs I consider antipatterns ;).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Task`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html), and call `updateProgress()` in order to update the progress in a way that throttles the calls to `Platform.runLater()`, so as not to flood the FX Application Thread with too many updates to perform.

So you can do:

```
public class ParseTask extends Task<Void> {

    private final Path file ;
    private long totalLines ;

    public ParseTask(...) {
        file = ... ;
        totalLines = ... ;
    }

    public Void call() throws IOException {

        // better to use AtomicLong here in case you parallelize the parsing 
        // at any point...
        AtomicLong linesRead = new AtomicLong() ;

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(file)) {
            stream.forEach(line -> {
                updateProgress(linesRead.incrementAndGet(), totalLines);
                // do stuff with line...
            });
        }

        return null ;
    }

    public long getTotalLines() {
        return totalLines ;
    }
}
```

then

```
public class DxProgressIndicator {

    private final VBox vb ;
    private ProgressBar pb;
    private ProgressIndicator pi;
    private TextField tfNumbers;
    private Label lblLineNumVal;
    private Label lblAllLines;
    private double progressIncrement;
    private double progressPrevVal;
    private int lineNum;
    private Label lblFile;

    private final DoubleProperty progress = new SimpleDoubleProperty();

    public DoubleProperty progressProperty() {
        return progress ;
    }

    public final double getProgress() {
        return progressProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setProgress(double progress) {
        progressProperty().set(progress);
    }

    public DxProgressIndicator() {

        lblFile = new Label();
        final HBox hbFile = new HBox();
        hbFile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Label lblCurrentFile = new Label("Current file: ");
        lblCurrentFile.setMinWidth(90);
        lblCurrentFile.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 13));
        hbFile.getChildren().addAll(lblCurrentFile, lblFile);

        pb = new ProgressBar(0);
        pb.setMinWidth(450);

        pi = new ProgressIndicator(0);

        pb.progressProperty().bind(progress);
        pi.progressProperty().bind(progress);

        final HBox hbPis = new HBox(10);
        hbPis.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hbPis.getChildren().addAll(pb, pi);

        lblLineNumVal = new Label();
        lblLineNumVal.setMaxWidth(200);

        Label slash = new Label("  /  ");

        lblAllLines = new Label();

        final HBox hbLines = new HBox();
        hbLines.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Label lblLineNum = new Label("    Currently parsing Line # :   ");
        lblLineNum.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
        hbLines.getChildren().addAll(lblLineNum, lblLineNumVal, slash, lblAllLines);

        tfNumbers = new TextField();
        tfNumbers.setEditable(false);
        tfNumbers.setMaxWidth(100);

        final HBox hbTrxValues = new HBox();
        hbTrxValues.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        Label lblNumbers = new Label("(transaction, step, record) = ");
        lblNumbers.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 12));
        hbTrxValues.getChildren().addAll(lblNumbers, tfNumbers);

        vb = new VBox(10);
        vb.getChildren().addAll(hbFile, hbPis, hbLines, hbTrxValues);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(10));

    }

    public Parent getRoot() {
        return vb ;
    }

    public void setTotalLines(long totalLines) {
        lblAllLines.setText(Long.toString(totalLines));
    }

}
```

And then just

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        ParseTask task = new ParseTask(...);

        DxProgressIndicator indicator = new DxProgressIndicator();
        indicator.setTotalLines(task.getTotalLines());
        indicator.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

        Scene scene = new Scene(indicator.getRoot());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Dexter Parser");

        primaryStage.show();

        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}
```

Obviously you may need to tinker with this for details - e.g. you can do `updateMessage(linesRead + " / " + totalLines);` and bind a label's text to the task's `messageProperty()` - but it should give you the basic idea.

Comment: Many thanks @James_D. I will incorporate this and report back.

Comment: Again, many thanks James. I started as not wanting to have my apps be JavaFX apps, simply call the GUI with updates when needed, but that proved to be convoluted somehow. I applied your method and it works very well. Thanks.

Comment: I have a question.The way `MyApp` is currently setup can only process one file at a time. What if in `call()` of `ParseTask`, I need to iterate over a directory of files and not just one! I got stuck after I implemented this approach. I think I need to manage several threads. If you could help, I could make a new post to see your answer clearly please. Thank you.

Comment: Solved the problem by creating a stage for every file in a loop as I don't mind them running concurrently. If you got ideas, still shoot them :-).

Comment: @mohsenmadi You can create as many `ParseTask`s as you need - one for each file  - and start each one in its own thread. You can create a `DxProgressIndicator` for each task. You don't need a separate window for each: you can, for example, create a `VBox` and call `vbox.getChildren().add(indicator.getRoot())` for each one. You could also do `task.setOnSucceeded(e -> vbox.getChildren().remove(indicator.getRoot()));`, so you remove the indicator when finished. This would behave like the progress monitor for copying files in Mac OSX.

Comment: Lovely! Will try this one :-)

Comment: Thaaaaank you! Works graciously :-)

Answer (score 1):

The javaFX Task class uses an atomic reference to coalesce updates such that they don't flood the event queue (which causes your problem). You could implement this mechanic in your code easily.

First you need a helper class:

```
private static final class ProgressUpdate {
     private final double workDone;        

     private ProgressUpdate(double p) {
          this.workDone = p;            
     }
}
```

Then you need a field which stores an atomic reference to objects of this class:

```
private static final AtomicReference<ProgressUpdate> progressUpdate = new AtomicReference<>();
```

and finally you can adapt your `updateProgress()` like this:

```
public static void updateProgress() {
    progressPrevVal += progressIncrement;
    if(progressUpdate.getAndSet(new ProgressUpdate(progressPrevVal)) == null){      
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            ProgressUpdate update = progressUpdate.getAndSet(null);
            pb.setProgress(update.workDone);
            pi.setProgress(update.workDone);
            lblLineNumVal.setText(Integer.toString(lineNum++));
        });
    }
}
```

This way there will only be a new update queued for the FX application thread if the GUI has already consumed the previous one.

However, you will be better of looking at this just to get an idea of how javaFX handles the problem internally and then proceed redesigning your code in a manner that you can use the built-in `Task` class of javaFX, which will automatically solve your current and possibly a number of otherwise upcoming problems.

Comment: Thanks calculator for your time. I tried your solution, but found that `progressUpdate` complaining about the `workDone` object! Did I miss anything?

Comment: @mohsenmadi it was a typo in my code. The field belongs to the update object.

Comment: Thank you very much @Calculator. Your method works well with the project I already wrote and didn't want to rewrite using the approach of James below. Much appreciated.